# Can we use `Using` block in WF 4?

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, using, using-statement

I'm very new to Workflow and a dummy in VB, so, I'm sorry for my weak question if it is.

I'm trying to implement a using block like this:

```
using (var db = new Dal.DataContextProxy())
{
   //My Codes
}
```

In a *sequence*, I want to initiate db in a using block. How should I do that? I tried Assign, but it seems I can not use *Using Block* in it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do with the standard activities but creating a using activity that exposes the db to it's children isn't hard. Make sure you think about workflow persistence as you probably couldn't persist and reload the workflow state in the middle of a block that has a SqlConnection open.

Comment: Thank you Maurice. Well, I think it's better to pass the db as Input Argument to the Activity. What do you suggest?

Comment: You mean as input to Using activity? Sure no problem. Create an activity very similar in structure to the ForEach where you take an input expression and expose that to the body and when the body is done call Dispose() on the input. That way you can create a new object or pass an existing in as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could try implementing your own `NativeActivity` to close the connection on the Complete/Fault handler as described at those [documentations and samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759031.aspx). In your particular scenario, as Maurice said, you must expose your DataContextProxy via [ExecutionProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358743.aspx).

Something similar(that applies to your scenario) is already done, and you can check it on [this Rory Primrose's blog post](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2011/03/10/Custom-DisposalScope-activity.aspx).